# Language dependent 'yes' command in linux, possible?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, locale

So apperently 'yes' command returns 'y' by default. It was working perfect with English as System Language in Ubuntu. Now I actually got a user who tries to run the software under Ubuntu with the German system language and it doesn't work as expected. It seems that the prompts expect 'j' or 'ja', but 'yes' still delievers 'y'.

Is there a way to make the output of 'yes' language dependent?
For now we started using
LC_ALL=C in the top of the script. But still evaluating if this is a good solution.

Comment: What speaks against using `yes j` in a German context?

Comment: `yes` isn't standardized, but every implementation I'm aware of lets you specify the string it outputs; `y` is just the default.

Comment: I don't think knowing or setting the locale necessarily tells you what input a command will expect.

Comment: Note: `yes` is used in scripts, and scripts should use "C" (not English) as default language (standardized output). Do you have a true case for a localized `yes` were different answer is the best solution? Or it is just a theoretical question?

Comment: @user1934428 'yes' is integrated into a script, that users can run on their own system with different default locales English/German/Chinese/Russian etc. If I fix it with 'yes j' the script will only work for German locale but not for English anymore.

Comment: @chepner experimentally we found out that setting the locale like I propose in the beginning of the script converts a question like 'Diesem Zertifikat vertrauen? [ja]/nein' 
to 
"Trust this certificate? yes/no" which works with the default 'y' output of 'yes' command.

Comment: Is `yes | LC_ALL=C some_command` an option? The rest of the script can use the user's preferred locale; only this command would use the C locale corresponding to the default output of `yes`.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm not fully aware of "C" meaning. But I think it has also something to do with one temporary solution I already mentioned in the answer. But the case I describe exists. User of "German" Ubuntu cannot use the original scripts, because prompts expect German answer.

Anyway we tested the things a little bit more right now and it seems like setting explicitly LC_ALL=C in the beginning of the script doesn't break anything else and fixes the issue.

Comment: (Better yet, does your command support an option that disables the *need* to read `y` or `j` from standard input?)

Comment: @chepner didn't think of that in this application. We use openssl and keytool. And it seems they have such options. Thanks.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : You have to make up your mind: Do you want the whole script to be multilingual? In this case just adapting the prompting letter of the `yes` command does not get you far; you also would have to test that the user indeed entered a `j`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, dug out this page: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/yes.c

and on line 63:

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
```

`""` means following in `setlocale`:

> If locale is an empty string, "", each part of the locale that should be modified is set according to the environment variables. The details are implementation-dependent.  For glibc, first (regardless of category), the environment variable LC_ALL is inspected, next the environment variable with the same name as the category (see the table above), and finally the environment variable LANG.  The first existing environment variable is used. If its value is not a valid locale specification, the locale is unchanged, and setlocale() returns NULL.

So it should get your system language, but it does not. (perhaps this might be a bug)

You best alternative is a alias.

Comment: But looking a few lines further down, and you can see the string `"y"` is hardcoded as the default, when no other values have been provided. And no call to `gettext` are done on that string, so I would argue that `yes` isn't internationalized. And even if it was by GNU that wouldn't help a person used BSD utils.

Comment: @andlrc tnx, so my answer should be it should but it does not.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your research. Was a good idea to look directly into the code, makes everything clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using support for different languages, you probably have a function that handels input.
Change that function so it will also accept `0` for `yes`, and `1` for `no` (`true` returns 0).
Once your software also accepts 0 and 1, you can use

```
yes 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
yes | sed 's/y/ja/'
```

More complex:

```
myes(){
    case ${LANG,,} in
        *en*) yes=yes;;
        *ru*) yes=да;;
        *gr*) yes=ja;;
        #...
    esac

    yes | sed "s/y/$yes/"
}
```

Looks like sed is not needed, just `yes $yes`

```
myes(){
    case ${LANG,,} in
        *en*) yes=yes;;
        *ru*) yes=да;;
        *gr*) yes=ja;;
        #...
    esac

    yes "$yes"
}
```

Comment: `yes ja` would be shorter and probably faster. But it doesn’t solve OP’s problem either.